# My API cannot read the passed data array using Curl

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I have a previous question here recently that has no answer at all. I tired everything I can but to no avail. NOw, I'm asking for another question since I figured something was not right in my code. Take a look at my code.

**My URL for the API with parameters**

```
http://localhost/sample/index.php/2/users/mil/minoza/09876543212
```

** The Array**

```
if ($request[0] == 2) {
$data = array(
  "table" => $request[1],
  "fname" => $request[2],
  "lname" => $request[3],
  "cntct" => $request[4]
);
```

**The code for the CURL and URL**

```
if ($request[0] == 2) {
   $str_data = json_encode($data);
   $post_elements = array('data'=>$str_data);
   echo $url_send;
   echo "</br>";
   print_r($post_elements);
   die();
   sput($url_send, $post_elements);
   echo sput($url_send, $post_elements);
}
```

**The sput function (CURL)**

```
function sput($url, $fields)
{

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    $post_field_string = http_build_query($fields);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_field_string);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

Scenarios:
You notice that in The code for the CURL and URL I have a echo, echo, print_r and a die. This i placed because I want to check if there's a data in the variables I'm going to use for the fucntion. And it does have data.

**Result**

```
http://localhost/api.php/
Array ( [data] => {"table":"users","fname":"mil","lname":"minoza","cntct":"09876543212"} )
```

**MY API.PHP**

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($method == 'PUT') {
   $data = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_shift($_POST));
   echo $data."AMF";
   die();
}
```

When I'm in api.php I dont know how will I get the data array I passed using the index.php Curl. Here's the result

```
AMF
```

is it right that I asked for the $_POST since in my CUrl in index.php there's a line in curl that states,

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_field_string);
```

Please someone helpme please. My previous question was totatlly ignored.

Thanks.

Comment: try this, json_decode($_POST, true);

Comment: This is the result when I tried your suggestion sir.
`Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\api.php on line 44
AMF`

Comment: how about, var_dump(json_decode($_POST, true));. if the result is array, you must print / echo with array param. ex: $decodeResult[0]

Comment: Like this?`$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($method == 'PUT') {
   var_dump(json_decode($_POST, true));
   die();
}`

Comment: what the result of that code? var_dump same like print_r it just for make sure which array that have been decoded. if result is array, you will see it and you can display with $example = json_decode($_POST, true); echo $example[0]; or echo $example[0][0];

Comment: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\api.php on line 43

Comment: In my function sput when i try to print_r a certain line like this `print_r($fields);` the result will be like this, I dont think this is one good array to begin with
`Array ( [data] => {"table":"users","fname":"mil","lname":"minoza","cntct":"09876543212"} )`

Comment: I also tried this one. ` $data = json_decode(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_shift($query)),true);
  echo $data."AMF";
  die();`
where `$data = json_decode(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_shift($query)),true);` is in line 43.
My error is `
Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\api.php on line 43`